# How for( ; ;) is infinite loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, language-agnostic, while-loop, infinite-loop

Like many other question explained that `while(true) {}` is an infinite loop and so is `for( ; ;)` my question is `while(true)` makes sense the conditions is always true but there is no vivid condition `true/false` in `for( ; ;)` so how is the later an infinite loop.

Comment: @pronox..  for(i=0;i<10;i++) Here some initialization and condition is there but for(;;) no condition ,nothing.. So infinite loop.

Comment: thanks but what is was looking for is cleared by @dasblinkenlight's answer.

Comment: @pronox: So your question is about C? Then you should tag it as such.

Comment: The behavior is mirrored in ECMAScript, Perl, and C++ as well as C, and in each case, it's a design decision for the language, not just an unintended consequence.  You don't see `if()...` defaulting to true, or `while()...` defaulting to infinite.  `for` was designed in each of those languages to intentionally have that behavior.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to Java Language Specification, section [14.14.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1.2):

> `for ( ForInit`<sub>opt</sub> `; Expression`<sub>opt</sub> `; ForUpdate`<sub>opt</sub> `) Statement`
>
> If the `Expression` is not present, or it is present and the value resulting from its evaluation (including any possible unboxing) is `true`, then the contained `Statement` is executed.

Since the standard treats missing expressions and expressions evaluating to `true` in the same way, the `for` loop with the missing expression is equivalent to an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks i was wondering how is no expression replaced by true or none zero constant. You standard clears this...

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify any condition to continue the loop, so it is executed forever.

Comment: For `for` loops, the "missing" condition is not an exit condition, it is a continue condition.

Answer (score 0):

The three parts of for loop: variable initialization, condition and variable update are optional. If the condition is absent, it is evaluated as true. The loop continues till something else in for loop block stops it. Since in your example for loop is empty, it is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

A loop becomes infinite loop if a condition never becomes `false`. The for loop is traditionally used for this purpose. Since none of the three expressions that form the for loop are required, you can make an endless loop by leaving the conditional expression empty.
When the conditional expression is absent, it is assumed to be **true**.

Answer (score -8):

The loop `for( ; ;)` is garbage. If that provides an infinite loop, it is at the control of that specific languages compiler that turns it into a infinite loop.

Comment: What??? This is an entirely portable construct!!! The standard is explicit about why it works.

Comment: This is an *extremely* common idiom in almost **all** C-based languages and any language that even has a for loop. -1